# Filter queryset with multiple checks, including value_is_in array in a Django view

Tags: django, django-views

I need to check if a user exists before saving a form. The fields are name, surname, and a role which can have one or many values. How can I do that?

```
def save(self, commit=True):
        profile = super(ProfileForm, self).save(commit=False)
        first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        surname = self.cleaned_data['surname']
        role = self.cleaned_data['role']

        if Profile.objects.filter(first_name=self.cleaned_data['first_name'], surname=self.cleaned_data['surname']).exists()
            raise forms.ValidationError("This profile already exists")

        elif commit:
            profile.save()
```

`Profile.objects.filter(first_name=self.cleaned_data['first_name'], surname=self.cleaned_data['surname'], role__in[role]).exists()` gives me `invalid syntax` error. Of course I want to check if name & surname & role are all present within the same profile.

**My models**

```
class Role(models.Model):
    type= models.CharField(max_length=30)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.type

class Profile(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)
    role = models.ManyToManyField(Role, blank=True)
```

Comment: `role__in=[role]` is the same as `role=role`.

Comment: Can you share your `Profile` model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pleasde do **not** check this in the form, you can check this in the model. Indeed, you can implement this with a [**`UniqueConstraint`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/constraints/#django.db.models.UniqueConstraint):

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                field=['first_name', 'last_name', 'role'],
                name='unique_name_and_role'
            )
        ]
```

The validation is done automatically in the `ModelForm`, so no need to worry about that, and this will also be enforced at the database level (if your database supports that).

Prior to [django-2.2](/questions/tagged/django-2.2), you can specify [**`unique_together`** [Djanog-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/options/#unique-together):

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = [['first_name', 'last_name', 'role']]
```

In case it is a `ManyToManyField`, you better enforce this at the **`.clean(..)`** method of the `Profile` model:

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):

    # …

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        surname = self.cleaned_data['surname']
        role = self.cleaned_data['role']
        if Profile.objects.exclude(pk=self.instance.pk).filter(
            first_name=first_name,
            surname=surname,
            role__in=role
        ).exists():
            raise ValidationError('A profile already exists.')
        return cleaned_data
```

In the view, you can then for example handle this with:

```
def my_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            # …
        else:
            return HttpResponseBadRequest('invalid data')
    # …
```

Comment: Thank you. Would this work for a role = models.ManyToManyField(Role, blank=True) though? It's an array (a single profile can have many roles).

Comment: I've added my models to my question.

Comment: @HBMCS: then you can indeed use `clean()`, see edit.

Comment: role__in=role in the .clean() method doesn't work; the .save() goes through and the method doesn't raise the validation error.

Comment: @HBMCS: but why do you wrap it in a list? Since `role` is a m2m, this means `self.cleaned_data['role']` is a `Queryset` as well. So it is `role__in=role`, not `role__in=[role]`.

Comment: yes, that was a mistake, see updated comment though; it doesn't catch the duplicate.

Comment: @HBMCS: it will only catch the duplicate given the other profile has exact the same `first_name`, `surname`, and at least one of the roles you select is already in the given `Profile`. Exactly *when* do you consider it a duplicate?

Comment: sorry, it's not that it doesn't catch the duplicate. It silently fails without rising the error. I have     form_profile = ProfileForm(request.POST or None)

    if form_profile.is_valid():
        form_profile.save()

in my view.

Comment: Yes, it's a duplicate with it's first_name: test, surname: test, role: 10, _exactly_ those fields.

Comment: @HBMCS: but did you override the `clean` method of the form?

Comment: sorry, I'm not sure I know what you mean; I put your code (the last answer) inside class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):. Do I need to put that cleaned_data variable somewhere?

Comment: @HBMCS: well you call `cleaned_data = super().clean()` to obtain the `cleaned_data`, next you can validate it, and `clean` should also *return* the cleaned data.

Comment: Yes, it should indeed. I mean, after putting that `clean()` method within my class `ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):`, is there something/somewhere else I'd need to change?

Comment: @HBMCS: please do not override `save()`, actually overriding it is not a good idea, since now it will not save the m2m relation at all. Is it possible to share the current version of your `ModelForm` (and perhaps the view as well)?

Comment: oh wait, my bad, the clean() method _is_ doing what is expected. The thing is that before I was grabbing the validation error in JavaScript with:   if ([404, 500 , 503, 504 ].indexOf(oReq.status) > -1){
      document.getElementById('errorProfile').innerHTML = 'This profile is already in the database'
          } . Now, though, with the clean() method returning the error, it doesn't grab the error 500 any more. It's a modal. How can I keep it open and show the error message?

Comment: @HBMCS: well normally `form.is_valid()` is `False` then, so you can return an error. That being said, return a 500-599 status code, is not really correct, since it is a "client error", which is in the 400-499 range. You can in that case for example raise a [`HttpResponseBadRequest`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseBadRequest) as response, and handle it in the JavaScript accordingly.

Comment: Fantastic, I now get "exceptions must derive from BaseException" but I'm definitely on the right track. And thanks SO much for the overridden save() method not saving the m2m() relation, that is part of my original issue. THANK YOU!!!

Comment: @HBMCS: sorry, I mean *return* a `HttpResonseBadRequest`, not *raise* :s.

Comment: how? `return HttpResponseBadRequest` at the end of the `clean()` method fails silently.

Comment: @HBMCS: I mean return it in the *view*, if `form.is_valid()` is `False`, so `if form.is_valid(): ... (do something) else: return HttpResponseBadRequest('Invalid data')`. Of course in the JavaScript, you need to handle then a status code in the 400-499 range.

Comment: ah, yes, of course, it makes sense. It all works as expected (returning error 400). Thank you again.

Comment: PS: can you please point me towards some documentation about the cons of, and alternatives to, overriding the `save()` method? I'd need to do that for another issue I have (i.e. I need to assign an id to related models saved in the same form: for now I have a form with the parent model which the user will submit first, then they'll have the same form with another form with related models appended which they'll submit a again so that I can append the parent's ID during the save; if I could have everything in one single page of course it'd be much better).

Answer (score 2):

invalid syntax is because of missing '=' sign after __in.
It should be something like below

```
Profile.objects.filter(first_name=self.cleaned_data['first_name'], surname=self.cleaned_data['surname'], role__in=self.cleaned_data[role]).exists()
```