# Django forms - nested filtering in a vew for form cleaned data validation

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-validation

This is related to [Filter queryset with multiple checks, including value_is_in array in a Django view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61826009/filter-queryset-with-multiple-checks-including-value-is-in-array-in-a-django-vi/61826065#61826065), though addresses a slightly different issue.

I need two levels of checking of my form data: I have a profile model with name, surname, and role (the last one is and array coming from a related model, one profile can have many roles).

Upon submission of the form I need to check if a profile with a name and surname exists first; if it does, I need to check if that existing profile has already that role; if yes, throw an error. If not, *keep the existing profile and only add the new role to the existing profile*.

My models:

```
class Role(models.Model):
    type= models.CharField(max_length=30)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.type

class Profile(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)
    role = models.ManyToManyField(Role, blank=True)
```

And this is what I have tried in my form:

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['name', 'surname', 'role']

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        name = self.cleaned_data['name']
        surname = self.cleaned_data['surname']
        role = self.cleaned_data['role']

        if Profile.objects.exclude(pk=self.instance.pk).filter(
            name=name,
            surname=surname,
            role__in=role # this would check for all three fields at the same time. That's not what I want. I also want a second layer of filtering (see description).

        ).exists():
            if role__in=role: # warning - pseudocode! This is just to show what I want to do.
                raise forms.ValidationError("This profile already exists")
            else: # append submitted role to EXISTING profile
        else:
            return cleaned_data
    return cleaned_data
```

and view:

```
def profile_add_view(request):

    form_profile = ProfileForm(request.POST or None)

    if form_profile.is_valid():
        form_profile.save()

    else:
        return HttpResponseBadRequest('This profile already exists.')
```

which of course gives me a syntax error on the second `if role__in=role:`. How can I check if the current Profile object being checked (the duplicated one coming from the `exists()` method) has the role specified in the form? Do I really need to use a for loop?

And also, how can I subsequently append only that role information to that existing role, without creating a new profile with a different role?

**Final code**

This is the final working code, also saving a new profile if a profile with that name and surname does not exist at all.

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super().clean()
    name = self.cleaned_data['name']
    surname = self.cleaned_data['surname']
    role = self.cleaned_data['role'][0]
    try:
        profile = Profile.objects.get(name=name, surname=surname)
        if profile.role.filter(type=role).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError("This profile already exists")
        else:
            # Add submitted role to existing Profile
            profile.role.add(role)
    except Profile.DoesNotExist:
        newprofile = Profile.objects.create(name=name, surname=surname)
        newprofile.role.add(role)
    pass
```

Comment: althogh your solution is certanly working, I would suggest a small refactorying to have a more standard behaviour of ProfileForm. You shouldn't save anything in clean(), since that would be an unexpected side effect upon calling is_valid(). Instead, I would create/modify the profile in save(), and use clean() for validation only, even if that means checking twice if the profile is an already existig one

Comment: OK, thank you, that's a good point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code in nice and clean, I like it ;)

I think this snippet could solve your use case:

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super().clean()
    name = self.cleaned_data['name']
    surname = self.cleaned_data['surname']
    role = self.cleaned_data['role']

    try:
        profile = Profile.objects.get(name=name, surname=surname)
        if profile.role.filter(type=role).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError("This profile already exists")
        else:
            # Add submitted role to existing Profile
            profile.role.add(role)
    except Profile.DoesNotExist:
        pass

    return cleaned_data
```

Comment: Hello, thanks. role__in works fine to me actually. Please read my question again: you're the second user (the first one deleted their answer now) who misunderstands my question, although I think it's quite clear.

Comment: Hello, sorry for misunderstanding. I updated my answer accordingly. Please note that in your Profile model "first_name" should be renamed as "name". br

Comment: Ah, that's better. Almost there: this code saves again an additional (duplicate) user with both roles, keeping the existing one there. Or actually, saves a new user with the newer role, and adds the new role to the existing one. Confusing.

Comment: I guess one solution would be of grabbing the role(s) of the existing profile, delete that one, and save a new profile with all the roles (old ones and new one).

Comment: The duplicate is being created because you are still calling `form_profile.save()` in your view. All you need to do is call `form_profile.is_valid()` and the change will be applied.

Comment: Good catch @MattRowbum: the second profile is created elsewhere, not in clean(). Or: override form_profile.save() and in there call super().save() only when really needed.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you for spotting that, @MattRowbum. It now works as expected.

Comment: @MattRowbum actually... how do I save new profiles now? I am checking if profiles with same name and surname and role exist, but now if a profile does not exist altogether it doesn't get saved. I would prefer not overriding the save() method if possible.

Comment: If I do  except Profile.DoesNotExist: profile.save() it complains that profile has been called before assignment.

Comment: You shouldn't call profile.save() in the exception handler inside clean(). From clean() just return cleaned_data array, then handle the creation of the new object in ProfileForm.save(). I think calling the super().save() in case Profile.objects.get(name=name, surname=surname) does not exists will just work

Comment: No, actually I solved it quite easily. I'm updating my question with the new final working code.